# How do I build Docker Machine from source ? (20.04)

Tags: docker, golang

I need to build Docker Machine from source. I've gathered that the easiest
way is to use GOPATH but I can't seem to find anywhere how to do it ?

I've got Docker Machine source code on my machine but where exactly it supposed to
be compiled ? Official Docker docs don't discuss this.

Can anyone provide steps ? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

**Edit:**
Output from `make` when ran inside `~/machine` source code directory:

```
...
...
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOROOT)
/home/mark/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOPATH)
cmd/docker-machine/machine.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/codegangsta/cli" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mark/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOPATH)
cmd/docker-machine/machine.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/codegangsta/cli" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mark/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOPATH)
cmd/docker-machine/machine.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/codegangsta/cli" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mark/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOPATH)
cmd/docker-machine/machine.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/codegangsta/cli" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mark/go/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: `GOPATH` is the path to your Go installation. Do you have Go installed on your computer? If not, the answer you receive will be a little bit longer ...

Comment: @Matigo  Go is installed on my computer. Version 1.15 and it is located in `/usr/local/go`

Answer (score 0):

To set the `GOPATH` variable on your machine, do this:

1. Open the `~/.profile` file using your preferred text editor and add the following two lines to the bottom of the file:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

2. Save the file, then reload your profile:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

This should give you a valid `GOPATH`

Comment: Thank you. I'll add output from running `make` inside the Machine's source.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the `github.com/docker/machine` hasn't been created. It also looks like the `github.com` directory should contain other directories or modules.